# Hosting subdomain without a name domain nginx

Tags: nginx, subdomain

I want to add a subdomain to my server. I do have have an ip address given by the hosting server but I don't have the name domain yet. Is it possible to host like:

```
subdomain.152.235.235.85 <-- I tried this by Is not working for me, perhaps this is not possible
```

Or is there a better way to have subdomain without having a name domain yet?

Answer (score 0):

If you want use this site for few devices, you can add to file **hosts**  your domain: `152.235.235.85 subdomain.test.site`

But just add subdomain to IP is impossible.